# Changing current directory to directory that have identifier as the substring

Tags: bash, grep, ls

My terminal is currently in the home directory, and the home directory contains a directory which have "round" as the substring.
Is there any way to directly change to that directory without typing the whole name of the directory? Like without executing:

```
cd dir_name
```

Or

```
cd identifier
```

Why the below command opens the secondary prompt instead of changing the directory

```
cd ls | grep identifier
```

Comment: Ya ``cd `ls |grep identifier` `` will work

Comment: what do you mean by identifier? An example would be better?

Comment: @clement it is not working, it opens a secondary prompt

Comment: @AvinashRaj identifier is the substring in the directory name, say name of dir is "abcdme" so identifier can be anything that uniquely identifies the dir like abcd,me etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly with bash you can't. The nearest thing that you can do is, if the identifier is at the start of the filename, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> so Bash autocomplete. Sadly, this won't work if the identifier is at the middle or end of the filename in which case I would recommend using zsh instead which allows this.

The `cd ls | grep identifier` didn't worked for two reasons, first, you were trying to change to a directory called `ls` and then pipe the stdout (which is empty) to grep looking for "identifier". This would be fixed if you used a subshell instead as clement suggested `cd $(ls | grep identifier)`. But this has other problem, ls output is in columns and grep works by lines. So if I for example try to grep "sites" in the folowing output:

```
➜ ls
autoreviewcomments.user.js  build.sh     build.xml  README.md  src
build.properties            build.sites  dist       SDK
➜ ls | grep sites
build.properties            build.sites  dist       SDK
```

or in some cases the color will be in the way of `cd`, so you must specify "no coloring":

```
cd $(ls | grep --no-color sites)
```

Comment: if I uses cd  ` ls| grep identifier,than why it opens a secondary prompt.
It should execute ls command first because of the " ` " operator
and than it should select the elements having identifier as the substring and than the output should be given to the cd command,correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @RAX you are missing another backtick act least. I prefer my own example in the end `cd $(ls | grep --no-color sites)` instead of using backticks.